# Why are MOSFETs used on the battery gauge lines?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, i2c, circuit-theory

This is from the iPhone 10, previous models didn’t have MOSFETs on the gauge lines so I’m wondering why they’re used now.

Is it so the phone can’t boot with just a voltage present from external supply without gauge lines, protection, or?

iPhone 10
[image: iphone10]

iPhone 6s
[image: iphone6s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> previous models didn’t have mosfets on the gauge lines so I’m wondering why they’re used now

The older iPhone 6s does not appear to use I²C signals for its battery gauge - those signals mention "SWI" on the partial schematic supplied.

The purpose of those MOSFETs in the iPhone 10 is explained on the partial schematic :-) It says:

> > Gas gauge I2C level translator

`Q3200` is the level translator for the SDA signal and `Q3201` is for the SCL signal. For these, the device shown is the [Rohm RV1C002UN MOSFET](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/datasheet/RV1C002UN/rv1c002un-e).

From the partial schematic, these signals on the iPhone 10 are 1.8V I²C signals, yet the gas gauge chip contained as part of the battery "module" is using a higher voltage (I don't know what voltage) for its I²C pull-ups. It appears that the relevant 1.8V I²C IC in the phone is unable to accept a higher voltage on the I²C signals, hence the need for level translation.

Using MOSFETs in this way, is a common, cheap, way to perform level translation for relatively slow signals. See [NXP Application Note AN10441: Level shifting techniques in I²C-bus design](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf). This technique is also explained in more detail in the old [Philips Application Note AN97055: Bi-directional level shifter for I²C-bus and other systems](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf).

Comment: So am I understanding it right that, the battery gauge chip on the battery itself is using a voltage higher than 1.8v on its i2c gauge lines, but the phone itself uses 1.8v on the i2c lines, so the two mosfets are acting as translators so the phone sees 1.8v on the two lines?

Comment: Note also that the 6s is using something other than I2C altogether.

Comment: @ohmmy - "*am I understanding it right that, the battery gauge chip on the battery itself is using a voltage higher than 1.8v on its i2c gauge lines, but the phone itself uses 1.8v on the i2c lines*" Yes, that is what I have tried to explain. The schematic itself say that those MOSFETs are being used for level translation and (although the 1.8V pull-ups must be elsewhere on the schematic and there are likely pull-ups inside the battery "module") this basic MOSFET design is typical for that purpose.

Comment: @Dave - Agreed; I'll amend my answer to make it clear that I'm only replying to the question about the iPhone 10, and not speculating about the older iPhone 6s circuit.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks I missed that. Is using i2c for battery gauge more accurate? Is there a reason it wasn’t used before in older models?

Comment: @ohmmy: Clearly, the battery packs are very different. They use different connectors, and the newer one is "smarter", with an on-board chip of some sort. It's likely that each phone is developed by an independent team, each one making different choices among the tradeoffs.